# Why one project (exe) does not see the namespace of another project (dll) in the same solution?

Tags: c#

Why one project (exe) does not see the namespace of another project (dll) in the same solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add a reference from the using project to the DLL first.

Select Project|Add Reference, Projects Tab.

Comment: Bring on the upvotes for being the first to give an obvious answer :)

Comment: @Adam, that just compensates the lack of votes for not-so obvious answers.

Answer (score 5):

A "solution" in Visual Studio is a collection of projects. Each project is independent of all the others. The solution is just a convenient way of organizing projects and opening them all together.

If one project is going to use the public objects defined in another project, then it must be compiled with a reference to the other project. This is true whether the projects are part of a single solution or not.

To signal to Visual Studio that the EXE must be compiled with a reference to the DLL, you must add the DLL to the EXE's list of references in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: +1 for the effort of clarifying a common misunderstanding of what a "solution" does.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to the DLL.

Right-click the EXE project, click Add Reference, go to the Projects tab, and select the DLL.

Also, make sure that the classes in the DLL are `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add a reference to the dll

Right click on the project --> Add Reference